# how to show only those sale order who has invoices? Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

The problem is that I can only filter sale order by field that is stored. But when its stored it is not triggered unless I trigger them by opening form and changing fields that he depends on. I want that they would be computed when tree view is opened and I could use those fields to filter records. (I have three different actions with different domains in which I use these three fields )

```py
route_id = fields.Many2one('route.data', string="Route ID")
has_route_req_po = fields.Boolean(compute='_compute_has_route_completed', store=True,
    help="Field is checked if So is Sale Order and has Route with status Req. Purchase") # SO IN PROGRESS
has_route_completed = fields.Boolean(
    compute='_compute_has_route_completed', store=True)  # SO TO INVOICE
has_r_completed_no_inv = fields.Boolean(
    compute='_compute_has_route_completed', store=True)  # SO FULLY INVOICED

@api.multi
@api.depends('route_id', 'state', 'route_id.route_state')
def _compute_has_route_completed(self):
    for so in self:
        if so.state == 'sale' and so.route_id:
            if so.route_id.route_state == 'draft' or so.route_id.route_state == 'in_progress':
                so.has_route_req_po = True
                so.has_r_completed_no_inv = False
                so.has_route_completed = False
            elif so.route_id.route_state == 'done':
                # Reikia patikrinti ar so turi saskaita
                invoice = self.env['account.invoice'].search([('origin', '=', so.name)])
                if invoice:
                    so.has_r_completed_no_inv = True
                    so.has_route_completed = False
                    so.has_route_req_po = False
                else:
                    so.has_route_completed = True
                    so.has_r_completed_no_inv = False
                    so.has_route_req_po = False
```

My actions that are called when menu items are clicked.

```xml
<record id="sales_data_action_sale_order_view1" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">In Progress</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">[('default_freight_service','=',1)]</field>
       <field name="domain">[('freight_service','=',True),('state','=','sale'),
            ('has_route_req_po','=',True)]</field>
        <field eval="False" name="view_id"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click to create a new.
          </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Other action is same with different domain:

```xml
     <field name="domain">[('freight_service','=',True),('state','=','sale'),
            ('has_route_completed','=',True)]</field>
```

And third action:

```xml
<field name="domain">[('freight_service','=',True),('state','=','sale'),
            ('has_r_completed_no_inv','=',True)]</field>
```

Comment: Maybe I can call search function when action is triggered in which I would show only those sale order who, let's say' has invoices.

Comment: Do you only need the sale orders that have at least one invoice no matter the state? or you need the other fields?